# Remove an element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering

I want to check if any element of a list contains `Missing["NotAvailable"]`
If so I want to delete the entire list. 
If I am correct I need to have some implementation of `MemberQ` and `DeleteCase`.

Example of what I want:

Input:

```
{{a,b},{Missing["NotAvailable"],c},{d,e}}
```

OutPut:

```
{{a,b},{d,e}}
```

Comment: So with minimal adjustment: `Select[list, FreeQ[_Missing]]` will do. There are probably better duplicates

Comment: @Kuba 13 seconds of difference!

Comment: @Szabolcs because noone cares to find list manipulation duplicates! :P

Comment: @Kuba I saw that you voted to close as duplicate (and I'm going to do the same), but I thought, if it's easy enough, why not post this one liner as an answer?  It should be helpful.  I'm not sure what's the best way to proceed in these cases, i.e. when I agree that it is a duplicate, is it wrong to still post a (more specific) answer before voting to close?  Answering and closing at the same time is somewhat contradictory. (I guess I should mention that I couldn't care less about rep points at this stage. I think neither do you.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I think there was a topic on meta about that, don't remember the conclusion though :P I'm not going to judge because I know I'm from the group that vote to close to often :)

Comment: @Kuba I decided to delete given that the duplicate has the exact same information.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways this could be done, e.g.

```
list /. {_Missing, _} :> Sequence[]
```

or missing any position:

```
list/. {___, _Missing, ___} :> Sequence[]
```

or

```
Cases[list, Except[{___, _Missing, ___}]]
DeleteCases[list, {___, _Missing, ___}]
Select[list,FreeQ[Missing][#]==True&]
Pick[list, FreeQ[Missing] /@ list]
True /. GroupBy[list, FreeQ[Missing]]
```

and many more...I leave it to play to look at advantages/disadvantages and what suits needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
(*data*)
list = {{a, b}, {Missing["not available"], c}, {d, e}};
Select[DeleteMissing @ # & /@ list, Length @ # == 2 &]
```

**Output:**

```
(*{{a, b}, {d, e}}*)
```

**Reference:**

[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)
[DeleteMissing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html)
[Length](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html)